# Building Apache Impala fails

Tags: apache, impala

I was trying to build Apache Impala from source(newest version on github).
I followed following instructions to build Impala:

(1) clone Impala

```
> git clone https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator-impala.git
> cd Impala
```

(2) configure environmental variables

```
> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-amd64 
> export IMPALA_HOME=<path to Impala> 
> export BOOST_LIBRARYDIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu 
> export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

(3)build

```
${IMPALA_HOME}/buildall.sh -noclean -skiptests -build_shared_libs -format
```

(4) errors are shown below:
[image]

Heap is needed to find the cause. Looks like the compiler does not support the GLIBCXX_3.4.21. But the GCC is automatically downloaded by the building script.

Appreciate your help!!!

Comment: What's your distro? This kind of issue needs detailed information of your env.

Comment: hi, Amos I use ubuntu 16.04. The gcc/++ version is 5.4.0. However, the Impala did not use my system gcc/g++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from this commit https://github.com/apache/impala/commit/d5cefe07c931a0d3bf02bca97bbba05400d91a48 , Impala has been shipped with a development bootstrap script.

I tried the master branch in a fresh ubuntu 16.04 docker image and it works fine. Here is what I did.

checkout the latest impala code base and do

```
docker run --rm -it --privileged -v /home/amos/git/impala/:/root/Impala ubuntu:16.04
```

inside docker, do

```
apt-get update
apt-get install sudo
cd /root/Impala
```

comment this out in `bin/bootstrap_system.sh` if you don't need test data

```
# if ! [[ -d ~/Impala-lzo ]]
# then
#   git clone https://github.com/cloudera/impala-lzo.git ~/Impala-lzo
# fi
# if ! [[ -d ~/hadoop-lzo ]]
# then
#   git clone https://github.com/cloudera/hadoop-lzo.git ~/hadoop-lzo
# fi
# cd ~/hadoop-lzo/
# time -p ant package
```

also add this line before `ssh localhost whoami`

```
echo "source ${IMPALA_HOME}/bin/impala-config-local.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
```

change the build command to whatever you like in `bin/bootstrap_development.sh`

```
${IMPALA_HOME}/buildall.sh -noclean -skiptests -build_shared_libs -format
```

then run `bin/bootstrap_development.sh`

You'll be prompted for some input. Just fill in default value and it'll work.

Comment: I will try this, Thank you!

Comment: It works! Thanks! It would be perfect if the community releases a docker image with all dependent library installed.

Comment: After this installation is complete, how you get to the shell? Sorry, I am new to Impala

Comment: It's a bit vague in memory now but I guess it's `${IMPALA_HOME}/bin/impala-shell.sh`

Comment: Tried:
impala@dev4impala:~/Impala/bin$ ./impala-shell.sh
./impala-shell.sh: line 24: exec: impala-python: not found

Comment: You need to source impala-config.sh first.   `source bin/impala-config.sh`